# Running MS Word macro commands in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create an excel macro that opens Word and creates a table. I made a macro in Word to create the table and copied it into the Excel macro. When I run it, I get this error:

run-time error '450'
wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment

at the point which excel is to execute the MS Word macro (which was recorded in Word):

```
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
    2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed
```

EDIT: I have set references for the Word doc

```
  '   Declare the variables
      Dim WordApp As Object
      Dim WordDoc As Object
      Dim wksSource As Worksheet

  '   Assign the active worksheet to an object variable
      Set wksSource = ActiveSheet

  '   Create an instance of the Word application
      Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  '   Make the Word application visible
      WordApp.Visible = True

  '   Open the specified Word document and assign it to an object variable
      Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Briet\Documents\PAJ\labels.dotm")
```

Comment: I think your Issue it the `Range Object`. `Range Objects` are not the same from excel to word. `Excel` uses `Cells` to define ranges `Word` uses Characters [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you add a reference to the Word object library in your Excel VBA project?

Comment: @engineersmnky, that makes sense to me. So if ranges don't translate between the two, how can I tell word to execute that command from excel? I tried 1) making a Word macro and Callling it in Excel, and 2) making a Word macro and and running SendKeys in Excel. Neither worked

Comment: Microsoft is not usually helpful but in this case they have provided a [KB Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508921%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to do just what you are asking it seems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added a reference to the Word Object Lirary in your Excel VBA project.

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim wd As Word.Application

Set wd = GetObject(, "word.application") 'get reference to open Word document

 wd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
    2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed

End Sub
```

Note that because `Selection` is a native Excel object, you need to qualify that to indicate you're referring to the Selection in *Word*

```
 wd.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Selection.Range
```

Comment: thanks for the response Tim. I have set the references already (see post edit). I also tried the code you provided. I get a Compile Error: user-defined type not defined